# Help Proving the Average is greater than B^(1/n)

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof, proof-explanation

> Let $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ be positive real numbers. Define the following two numbers:
>
> $A = (a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n) /n $ (The average of the numbers)
>
> $B = (a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n)^{1 / n}$
>
> Prove that $A \geq B$.

This is what I'm trying to prove for an assignment, and I'm not sure where to start or how do do it. Yes, I can do a base case, and inductive hypothesis, but I'm not sure where to go from there for proving $k+1$. Any hints are appreciated on how to show that this hold true for all positive integers.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=\frac{1}{16}$. Then $A=\frac{1}{16}$.

Note that $B=(1/4)^{1/4}\gt A$.

Perhaps $B$ is supposed to be $(a_1\cdots a_n)^{1/n}$.

Comment: I believe $a_{1} = 1, a_{2} = 2, a_{3} = 3$ divided by 3 is what is implied by the equation for $A$ it follows that $B = (1+2+3)^{1/n}$ which holds true. Does that clear up what the question is asking?

Comment: @2manyints:  As the result is currently stated, it is not true. It is hard to speculate about how to modify the statement so that it will become true. If this is a problem from a book or assignment, I would suggest carefully checking whether the question as posted is *exactly the same* as the book question.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying and this is exactly the way the problem is given to me. And I guess that is a counter example to proof. Guess i'll have to consult the prof on this one. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: You are welcome. If instead we had $B=(a_1\cdots a_n)^{1/n}$, this would be the famous Arithmetic Mean Geometric Mean Inequality (AM/GM), a little tough to prove in an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

For $a_1=a_2=1/2$ and $n=2$, it is false.